# Cannot connect Socket.io Node (AWS EC2) from React Application ( AWS Amplify) polling (400) bad request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, socket.io, aws-amplify

**Note: ALL is WORKING FINE in Local ENV**

HI, i have deployed my backend on AWS EC2 port 80 with SSL certificate and everything. It is currently working fine with React application except socket connection. which gives following errors
[image]

[image]

[image]

here is my client code:
"socket.io-client": "^4.5.3",

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
socket.current = io(`ws://${process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL}`);
```

Server side code:
"socket.io": "^4.5.3",

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  autoConnect: false,
  cors: {
    origin: [
 process.env.FrontEnd_URL,
    ],
    credentials: true,
  },
});
```

Any Help will be Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It seems your server is not reachable, could you please check the troubleshooting steps [there](https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#the-server-is-not-reachable)?

Reference: https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/